# Page break HTML CSS - print for invoice in PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, document, invoice

I have a task where I need to implement an invoice system that produces an HTML web page of the invoice, which is then printed to a PDF file.

The invoice that I'm outputing is shown in the following image.

[image]

What I now need to do is alter my code, so that it produces page breaks at the page boundaries to match the page size of my PDF output.  Currently it does not do this, but instead just keeps printing an extended image across the pages that are printed.

Here is the HTML Code I'm currently using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <style></style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 52.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm;">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Das ist ein Text</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 57.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 30.0mm; width: 60.0mm;">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Das ist ein Test</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 100.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 7.0mm; width: 107.0mm;">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Headline</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 110.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 20.0mm; width: 178.0mm;">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Introduction Text</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 243.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 3.0mm; width: 170.0mm;">
            <hr style="margin-top: 2mm; margin-bottom: 0mm; width: 170.0mm; border-color:#000000; height: 1.0mm" />
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 247.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 30.0mm; width: 70.0mm;page-break-after:auto ">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Footer1</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 247.0mm; left: 120.0mm; height: 30.0mm; width: 70.0mm;page-break-after:auto ">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Footer2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5mm; border-color: #000000; background-color: null; position: absolute; top: 10.0mm; left: 140.0mm; height: 40.0mm; width: 50.0mm;">
            <span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Logo</span>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 150.0mm; left: 20.0mm; height: 50.0mm; width: 170.0mm; page-break-after:always;">
            <table style="page-break-after:always;">

                <tr style="page-break-after:always;">
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #005fbf">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Position</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Artikelnr</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Beschreibung</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Menge</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Preis (Netto)</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Preis (Brutto)</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Gesamtsumme (Netto):</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="middle" style="height: 5.0mm; width: 70.0mm; background-color: #none">
                        <div style="text-align: center;">
                            <span style="text-align: center; font-size:11px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                                <strong>Gesamtpreis (Brutto)</strong>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

<tr>

<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">2</span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"></span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">1.0</span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">0</span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">0.0</span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">0.0</span></td>
<td style="background-color: #none"<span style="font-size:11px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">0.0</span></td>
</tr>               

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**please note I have trimmed down my sample code as it was too big for stack overflow**

How can I make this code split cleanly on the correct page boundaries so that each of the table sections in my html appears as a closed box when I print the PDF out in the browser.

Comment: and update on you q, already solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an element a page break property.

```
page-break-after: auto|always|avoid|left|right|initial|inherit;
```

Or if you want to page break inside an element you can use the page-break-inside property.

```
page-break-inside: auto|avoid|initial|inherit;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I know this already. But I need help in my posted code. Could you help me, please

Comment: I've just edited your post beacuse the HTML you pasted in was way too big for an SO post, and as a result, trying to get it formatted correctly wasn't happening.  I would suggest you host the full code  on some service like paste bin, then put a link to that if you need people to see the absolute full html code in all it's gory detail :-)

Comment: Use a better solution maybe? Take some inspiration from here where you can upload an XML, design the "Invoice" and let it handle the breaks in pages and such. http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus.Editor?http://cdn.xportability.com/Samples/Invoice.html

Comment: XML is no option for me. I want to use HTML. How should I change the posted HTML code for solving this issue for the table?